# Unable to run a cloned project in IntelliJ (Failed to collect dependencies)

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to Spring and IntelliJ, i have to clone a repo from GitHub and to setup the development environment on the PC.

The issue is that once i've installed the IntelliJ (Community) and cloned the repo, once i try to run "mvn package" or "clean install" i always get the same error:

```
PS E:\Projects\Vanity\vanity-server> mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< it.igesa.vanity:vanity-server >--------------------
[INFO] Building vanity server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/itext-2.1.7.js6.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.255 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-13T09:06:46+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project vanity-server: Could not resolve dependencies for project it.igesa.vanity:vanity-server:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.7.1 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js6 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/, default, releases+snapshots), jr-ce-releases (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases, default, releases+snapshots), jr-snapshots (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-snapshots/, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I've yet tried to delete the repo and clone it again, uninstall and reinstall IntelliJ, install Maven manually but nothing of that worked..

I've tried to invalidate the cache and restart IntelliJ, Generate Source and Update folders...

I had yet installed Android Studio in my PC could it be the issue?

My colleague doesn't have any issue with it so i think it's a configuration issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing the version of net.sf.jasperreports dependency from **6.7.1** to **6.17.0** in `pom.xml`